# Imagem de fundo cobrindo o navdrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Tenho uma activity com um navdrawer nela. E gostaria de colocar uma imagem de fundo nesta activity.
Mas quando coloco a imagem, o nav some, a imagem fica por cima dele. O nav não perde a função, se clicar em cima da imagem ele abre normalmente, mas não aparece. Como posso resolver esta questão?

XML abaixo:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:background="@drawable/fundo"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnRoute"
            android:layout_width="223px"
            android:layout_height="327px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rota"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnKeeper"
            android:layout_width="223px"
            android:layout_height="224px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnRoute"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnRoute"
            android:background="@drawable/keeper"
        />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnMap"
            android:layout_width="223px"
            android:layout_height="223px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnKeeper"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnKeeper"
            android:background="@drawable/prevencao"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: Imagem1, sem o fundo]

[image: Imagem2, com o fundo]

Imagem ou background deve ficar no android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout .. e não no relative layout .. solução foi esta

Comment: Resolvido. Deve ficar no android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout e  não no relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

Imagem ou background deve ficar no android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout .. e não no relative layout

Comment: Esta sua resposta já é a solução do caso?